# Does the AXI interconnect need to subtract the offset address after decoding operation is done

Tags: bus, soc, axi4, axi

The Address decoder in the AXI interconnect will based on the incoming address to determine which slave device to be targeted to.

Question is does the AXI interconnect need to subtract the offset address if the targeted slave is on 2nd AXI port or onwards?

For example:

1st slave address range: 0 - 3FFF

2nd slave address range: 4000 - 7FFF

If the Master is targeting 2nd slave device & the destination device is only recognizing valid range of address which is 0 from 3FFF. What address should the AXI interconnect output?

Comment: Does the below response answers your question/queries?

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming 32-bit bus with two slaves and one master connected to the interconnect...*

`Base address + offset` is given to interconnect by master. The interconnect decodes it (using upper bits) and forwards **only** the offset address (at lower bits) to **one** of the two slave ports. i.e., it initiates read/write transaction on **one** of the two slaves only.

Suppose master wants to read the second register in second slave. What it does is: it sends address `4004H` to interconnect for a read transaction, the interconnect will  translate the address to `0004H`. And does read transaction **only** on the second slave. The data read from the slave by interconnect is then sent to the master.